# Secondary monitor not displaying colours correctly

Tags: windows-7, external-display, projector

I have an MSI notebook with a Radeon HD card and Windows 7 installed. I use EasyWorship. The colours on the monitor are correct, but when connecting to a projector the white colour is displayed as yellowish.

I tried playing around with the colour/display settings on the secondary VGA monitor but then the other colours are impacted.

Do I have to upgrade the drivers or is there another solution?

Comment: Does the projector display yellow-ish when plugged into something else?

Comment: Does any other displays seem yellowish when connected to the notebook?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a broken VGA cable - in detail the cable responsible for the blue color (red + green = yellow). Alternatively the error may also be located inside the projector.

You can test that by displaying an image that has uses only the colors black and blue. If the blue color is missing you have with a high probability a hardware problem.